# Is it possible to pass a model data as a parameter of SQL stored procedure from API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api

I am new to .NET and I am working on an API project. In this project, I am receiving a model class as a parameter in one of the API method.

I want to know that can I pass the model data to the stored procedure for INSERT operation in database.

Or please tell me what is the best practice to store the model data to database from API

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SAVE_USER_ADDRESS(AddressModel model)
{
    ...........
    ..........
}
```

Model class :

```
public class AddressModel
{
        public string mAddressTitle { get; set; }
        public string mFirstName { get; set; }
        public string mLastName { get; set; }
        public string mMobileNumber { get; set; }
        public string mArea { get; set; }     
}
```

Can anyone help me solve this?

Comment: Entity framework or other types of ORM

Comment: Normal API project ,not  a Entity Frame Work.@蕭為元

Comment: @Zhu ¿How are you accesing to the BBDD?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Datalayer you are using, you can pass the parameters to the Database.
Some Sample options

1. Entity Framework - If your Model class is the same as Entity Framework Models. Then you can update the record easily or even make use of Stored Procedures and call them as Methods.
2. Custom Datalayer Classes (using ADO.NET) - You can design a Datalayer where you pass the Model as a parameter and pass the values from Model to the DB via ADO.NET.